# Flask list of last visited pages AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'set_cookie'

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make a list of the last visited pages using sessions. I keep getting the error `AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'set_cookie'`
I think the `@app.after_request` part is the cause, but I don't know how to fix it.

Python code

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    session['urls'] = []

    data = []
    if 'urls' in session:
        data = session['urls']

    timestamp = None

    t = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    (h, m, s) = t.split(':')
    result = int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)

    if 0 <= result < 43200:
        timestamp = 'Goedemorgen'
    elif 43200 <= result < 64800:
        timestamp = 'Goedemiddag'
    elif 64800 <= result:
        timestamp = 'Goedeavond'

    resp = make_response(render_template('index.html', timestamp=timestamp, data=data))
    resp.set_cookie('visited', 'visited', expires=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=2))
    return resp


@app.after_request
def store_visited_urls(self):
    session['urls'].append(request.url)
    if(len(session['urls']) > 5):
        session['urls'].pop(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'set_cookie'
```

The above error indicates that the object `resp` has `Nonetype` which means `make_response` is returning `None`.
That takes me to your `make_response` function which is fine except the parameters you are passing through it.

The problem lies here :

```
def index():
    session['urls'] = []
```

Whenever you are invoking the request for `'/'` you are initializing the `sessions['url']` to an empty list therefore the data also gets nothing in the following statement:

```
if 'urls' in session:
        data = session['urls']
```

You need to seperately initialize the `sessions['url']` then use it in the `index()` function.

Having said that I assume you have set the `app.secret_key` to some secret key of yours.

Your `after_request` looks fine to me though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you actually need to return the response object at the end of the @app.after_request

If you don't return it, it doesn't send it back to Flask for attaching session data to.

```
@app.after_request
def store_visited_urls(request):
    session['urls'].append(request.url)
    if(len(session['urls']) > 5):
        session['urls'].pop(0)
    return request
```